# Override file access functions with statically linked musl (to implement a read-only virtual FS)

Tags: c, static-linking, musl

If `dlsym` is available in dynamic linking setup, I can get access to the original impl pointers using `dlsym` with `RTLD_NEXT` and use them in my overrides, e.g. as follows:

```cpp
// paste these in main.c

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int open(const char *path, int flags)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "log_file_access_preload: open(\"%s\", %d)\n", path, flags);

    typedef int (*orig_open_func_type)(const char *pathname, int flags);
    orig_open_func_type orig_func = (orig_open_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    return orig_func(path, flags);
}

FILE* fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "log_file_access_preload: fopen(\"%s\", \"%s\")\n", path, mode);

    typedef FILE* (*orig_fopen_func_type)(const char *path, const char *mode);
    orig_fopen_func_type orig_func = (orig_fopen_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    return orig_func(path, mode);
}
```

Is there a way to do static linking in such a way that doesn't hide the original libc/POSIX symbols and so that I can use them in my overrides? Should I create my own copy of musl `*.a` files with renamed original symbols? Should it work? Is there another way?

Usecase: implement redirection of file read/access functions for a custom LaTeX program (compilation process is controlled by me, statically built with musl) to read files from ISO or TAR archive (that contains a prepared TeX Directory Structure) without extraction to disk

Comment: `do static linking` Statically, you have control. Rename symbol fopen to __musl_fopen in musl static library. Then link, and use __musl_fopen in your code. `Should I create my own copy of musl *.a files with renamed original symbols?` Yup.

Comment: Another approach: `latex <(catTarMember foo.tar member.tex)` https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html